# Using everything() from tidyselect in dplyr to select a variable last

Tags: r, select, dplyr, tidyselect

I would like to programmatically tell what column I'd like to display **LAST**. The function `everything()` from tidyr is great when it is used as the last argument --you specify everything before it and let it do the rest

But what if I want to do it the other way-- say what variable I want **last**, and then have `everything()` (or another function) provide all variables not selected before it.

Suppose in the example below I'd like to select cyl as the last variable to display...

```r
library(tidyverse)

data = mtcars %>% as_tibble() %>% select(1:4)

data %>% select( cyl,everything()) #works -- cyl at beginning
#> # A tibble: 32 × 4
#>      cyl   mpg  disp    hp
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     6  21    160    110
#>  2     6  21    160    110
#>  3     4  22.8  108     93
#>  4     6  21.4  258    110
#>  5     8  18.7  360    175
#>  6     6  18.1  225    105
#>  7     8  14.3  360    245
#>  8     4  24.4  147.    62
#>  9     4  22.8  141.    95
#> 10     6  19.2  168.   123
#> # … with 22 more rows

data %>% select(everything(), cyl) #does not work! -- cyl not at end!
#> # A tibble: 32 × 4
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21       6  160    110
#>  2  21       6  160    110
#>  3  22.8     4  108     93
#>  4  21.4     6  258    110
#>  5  18.7     8  360    175
#>  6  18.1     6  225    105
#>  7  14.3     8  360    245
#>  8  24.4     4  147.    62
#>  9  22.8     4  141.    95
#> 10  19.2     6  168.   123
#> # … with 22 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I would want it to look like this

```
data %>% some_fxn() 
# A tibble: 32 × 4
     mpg  disp    hp   cyl
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  21    160    110     6
 2  21    160    110     6
 3  22.8  108     93     4
 4  21.4  258    110     6
 5  18.7  360    175     8
 6  18.1  225    105     6
 7  14.3  360    245     8
 8  24.4  147.    62     4
 9  22.8  141.    95     4
10  19.2  168.   123     6
# … with 22 more rows
```

Is there another function or an option to `everything()` to allow it to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `relocate()` verb

```
data %>% 
  relocate(cyl, .after = last_col())
```

If you are going to often move things to the end of the data.frame, you can write your own helper

```
relocate_end <- function(..., .after=NULL) {
  relocate(..., .after=last_col())
}
```

and this will work with multiple columns as well

```
data %>% relocate_end(cyl, mpg)
#    disp    hp   cyl   mpg
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1  160    110     6  21  
#  2  160    110     6  21  
#  3  108     93     4  22.8
#  4  258    110     6  21.4
#  5  360    175     8  18.7
#  6  225    105     6  18.1
#  7  360    245     8  14.3
#  8  147.    62     4  24.4
#  9  141.    95     4  22.8
# 10  168.   123     6  19.2
```

Comment: I have been using tidyverse for ages and did not know about the `relocate()` function. Does exactly what I want and easy to code/understand. The helper function can make it even easier. Thank you very much MrFlick!

Answer (score 1):

To get everything except `cyl`, just use `-cyl`.

```r
data %>% select(-cyl, cyl)
#> # A tibble: 32 x 4
#>      mpg  disp    hp   cyl
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21    160    110     6
#>  2  21    160    110     6
#>  3  22.8  108     93     4
#>  4  21.4  258    110     6
#>  5  18.7  360    175     8
#>  6  18.1  225    105     6
#>  7  14.3  360    245     8
#>  8  24.4  147.    62     4
#>  9  22.8  141.    95     4
#> 10  19.2  168.   123     6
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks Allan -- that certainly does work and I had not thought about this method. I wish it was a little cleaner though as this might be difficult to interpret/code if we had a handful of variables that we wanted at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
data %>% select(setdiff(colnames(data) , "cyl") , cyl)
```